# Save data using graphql and AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, graphql, aws-amplify

I am getting data from an API and would like to save to amplify backend using AWS Lambda and graphql. The process fails but I am not sure why it's failing or whether I have written the correct code. This is my second function and I would appreciate help. My code is as below:

```
/* Amplify Params - DO NOT EDIT
    API_MOCKBETS_GRAPHQLAPIENDPOINTOUTPUT
    API_MOCKBETS_GRAPHQLAPIIDOUTPUT
    API_MOCKBETS_GRAPHQLAPIKEYOUTPUT
    ENV
    REGION
Amplify Params - DO NOT EDIT */

var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var awsServerlessExpressMiddleware = require("aws-serverless-express/middleware");

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(awsServerlessExpressMiddleware.eventContext());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
  next();
});


const axios = require("axios");
const gql = require("graphql-tag");
const graphql = require("graphql");
const { print } = graphql;

const createCountry = gql`
  mutation createCountry($input: CreateCountryInput!) {
    createCountry(input: $input) {
      id
      country_id
      country_name
      country_logo
    }
  }
`;

app.get("/leagues", function (req, res) {
  axios
    .get(
      "https://apiv2.apifootball.com/?action=get_countries&APIkey=redacted"
    )
    .then(async (response) => {
      for (const countryData of response.data) {
        try {
          const graphqlData = await axios({
            url: process.env.API_URL,
            method: "post",
            headers: {
              "x-api-key": process.env.API_mockbets_GRAPHQLAPIKEYOUTPUT,
            },
            data: {
              query: print(createCountry),
              variables: {
                input: {
                  country_id: countryData.country_id,
                  country_name: countryData.country_name,
                  country_logo: countryData.country_logo,
                },
              },
            },
          });
          res.json({
            body: "successfully created country!",
          });
        } catch (err) {
          res.json({
            err,
          });
        }
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.json({ err });
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("App started");
});

module.exports = app;
```

How can this be modified to achieve my objective?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to make the code work by removing and refactoring some parts. The final code is as follows:

```
/* Amplify Params - DO NOT EDIT
    API_MOCKBETS_GRAPHQLAPIENDPOINTOUTPUT
    API_MOCKBETS_GRAPHQLAPIIDOUTPUT
    API_MOCKBETS_GRAPHQLAPIKEYOUTPUT
    ENV
    REGION
Amplify Params - DO NOT EDIT */

var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var awsServerlessExpressMiddleware = require("aws-serverless-express/middleware");

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(awsServerlessExpressMiddleware.eventContext());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
  next();
});

const axios = require("axios");
const gql = require("graphql-tag");
const graphql = require("graphql");
const { print } = graphql;

const createCountry = gql`
  mutation createCountry($input: CreateCountryInput!) {
    createCountry(input: $input) {
      id
      country_id
      country_name
      country_logo
    }
  }
`;
const listCountries = gql`
  mutation listCountries($input: CreateCountryInput!) {
    listCountries(input: $input) {
      id
      country_id
      country_name
      country_logo
    }
  }
`;

const apiURL = "redacted";
const apiKey = "redacted";

app.get("/leagues", function (req, res) {
  axios
    .get(
      "redacted"
    )
    .then(async (response) => {
      for (const countryData of response.data) {
      
        await axios({
          url:apiURL,
          method: "post",
          headers: {
            "x-api-key": apiKey,
          },
          data: {
            query: print(createCountry),
            variables: {
              input: {
                country_id: countryData.country_id,
                country_name: countryData.country_name,
                country_logo: countryData.country_logo,
              },
            },
          },
        });
      }
    });
  res.json({
    body: "successfully created country!",
  });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("App started");
});

module.exports = app;
```